# How to build an interactive map like the ones attached

Tags: javascript, dictionary, dashboard

How best can I build an interactive Nigerian map like the ones attached? I want to build a dashboard with the colour of each state different from the other.

[A Nigerian Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw4jV.jpg)

[Nigerian Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkae5.jpg)

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this?

Comment: Can you point me to the resources on how to replicate this in a project I am working on? Thanks

Comment: As you already found two working examples, why not inspect their markup?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.